# Copying contents of one file to another leaves the other file empty

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, file-io, ofstream

I'm trying to copy the contents of `document1.txt` to `document2.txt` using this simple program:

```
int main() {
    ifstream in("document1.txt");
    ofstream out("document2.txt");
    string str;
    while(getline(in,str))
        out<<str;
}
```

But, when I run the program, I find that `document2.txt` is still empty.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you check if the files actually open?

Comment: You're not explicity closing the streams, so they won't be flushed/closed until they go out of scope.  Is this your entire program, or is other stuff happening afterwards?

Comment: @ Ali Alamiri. Thanks for your reply. I created them manually at the beginning. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Please post some of your code how you "created", opened and closed them.

Comment: @benjymous. Yes, this is the whole program

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820483/copying-contents-of-one-file-to-another-in-c

Comment: @Blacktempel. I have manually created `document1.txt` and `document2.txt`

Comment: Do you actually close the files ?

Comment: @Blacktempel. I'm kind of new to `C++`. What should I do for closing the files? Is there a function `close` for instance?

Answer (score 1):

```
    ifstream in("document1.txt");
    ofstream out("document2.txt");
    string str;
    while(getline(in,str))
    {
        out<<str;
    }
    in.close(); // <---
    out.close(); // <---
```

There is a function to close it. Please check this: [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/close/) and [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/).

Comment: When either stream object goes out of scope, they will be destructed and close the stream. There is no need to explicitly calls `close`.

Answer (score 1):

*"I have manually created `document1.txt` and `document2.txt`"*

In case you are running your program directly from Visual Studio, note that the working directory is set to `$(ProjectDir)` by default, i.e. these files must be placed at the same directory where your project file (`.vcproj` / `.vcxproj`) is.

You could either place them to the appropriate directory or specify the full path, for example place them directly to `C:` and in code do:

```
ifstream in("C:\\document1.txt");
ofstream out("C:\\document2.txt");
```

This is something you would notice if you outputted something in case of an error while opening:

```
if (!out.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Can not open document2.txt" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Note that in this case you don't actually need to flush any buffer, neither close the streams explicitly. All of this will happen automatically when these objects are destructed, i.e. when the execution goes out of scope.

Comment: I have specified the full path as you recommended, and the documents I have created are in the same project's folder, but still having the same issue. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Simplicity: Did u add the lines that check whether `out.is_open()` ? Did it output an error?

Comment: @Simplicity: Also do not create the output file explicitly. Let your program create it.

Comment: Yes, I have added the check before the while loop and have remoced the `document2.txt` that I have created manually, and didn't have any error. But, the issue remains...

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream document1("document1.txt");
ofstream document2("document2.txt");
string str;
getline(document1, str);
document2<< str<< endl;
document1.close();
document2.close();
```

Try this code. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream in("document1.txt");
    ofstream out("document2.txt");
    string str;
    while(getline(in,str))
        out<<str<<endl;
}
```

document1.txt

```
aaaaaaaa
bbb bbb
c c c c
d
```

under command line you can do

```
$g++ test.cpp -o test.out
$test.out
```

And then you will get document2.txt

```
aaaaaaaa
bbb bbb
c c c c
d
```

**P.S.** All the code tested under Mac and Linux 
**P.S.** if you change 9th line of test.cpp from `out<<str<<endl;` to `out<<str;`

document2.txt would becomes

```
 aaaaaaaabbb bbbc c c cd
```

because the `getline(in,str)` function would extracts characters from `in` and stores them into `str` until '\n' or *end-of-file* is found.
Which means `str` does not contains '\n'. You need to add '\n' by yourself.
**P.S.** under C++, as LihO says, you don't need to close `in` and `out`, since `in` and `out` would be closed at line 10 `}`
Also, you don't need to flush when you execute line 9, since `endl` has flush function.